# Running 2 functions in parallel at the same time with parameters from 2 different lists in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have 2 functions that are used to fetch the contents of two separate websites.

```
crawlFunctionSiteA()
crawlFunctionSiteB()
```

I have additionally 2 lists of URLs to be fetched and they should be passed to their corresponding functions as parameters. As you can see they're divided by site:

```
listURLSiteA = ['url1','url2','url3']
listURLSiteB = ['url4','url5','url6','url7','url8']
```

listUrlSiteB is longer than listURLSiteA. What I want to be able to do is to execute crawlFunctionSiteA() and crawlFunctionSiteB() at the same time, passing the parameters from listURLSiteA to crawlFunctionSiteA() and listURLSiteB to crawlFunctionSiteB(). Probably listURLSiteA will be crawled faster than listURLSiteB.

I tried doing:

```
executors_list = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for i in listURLSiteA:
        executors_list.append(executor.submit(crawlFunctionSiteA(), i))
    for j in listURLSiteB:
        executors_list.append(executor.submit(crawlFunctionSiteB(), j))
```

The code runs fine but I get wrong results. Analyzing my output I found out that the script was running crawlFunctionSiteA('url1') and crawlFunctionSiteA('url2') at the same time and not completely.

Any ideas how to do what I'm looking for ?

Comment: Why don't you run a separate script/process for ``crawlFunctionSiteA`` and ``crawlFunctionSiteB`` each? What do you mean by "at the same time and not completely"? Do the functions interact in any way? Are you aware that ``executor.submit(crawlFunctionSiteA(), i)`` *runs* ``crawlFunctionSiteA``, *then* creates a future of passing ``i`` to the result of ``crawlFunctionSiteA``?

Comment: 2 separate scripts / files would be doable but not so elegant.....When you say 2 processes, how do you mean that ? The functions write data to the same database, but they don't interact. No, I am not aware about that and fairly inexperienced regarding parallel processing. Passing only 1 url to each function and without the for loop works perfectly. The problem is the list.

Comment: With this particular code, crawlFunctionSiteA() did crawl url1 and url2 in parallel and not sequentially. I've studied the output and I could notice there. Somehow many values were skipped. No idea why. The functions work fine when passing only one URL to each (not from a list).